# VueJS does not rerender list even though array has changed & v-key is specified

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have two entities: categories and subcategories and two lists. When user selects a category I display subcategory list.

At first try it works fine, but when I change category I got old subcategory list.

Both categories and subcategories are in vuex store.

I tried to calculated subcategories next ways:

1. Computed property
2. When user selects a category I invoke a method, which filters subcategories by category_id and returns new list

Nothing worked for me. Here is an example of computed property:

```
subCategories() {
  return this.getClothingSubCategories.filter((subCategory) => {
    return subCategory.clothing_category_id === this.category.clothing_category_id
  })
},
```

Where `this.getClothingSubCategories` is a vuex getter.

What's weird is that both in vue plugin (in chrome developer tools) and console I got the list updated, but in html the list is old.

Here is how I display the list:

```
<VuePerfectScrollbar class="categories"
                     v-if="showSubCategories"
                     v-once>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="subCategory in subCategories"
        :key="subCategory.clothing_subcategory_id"
        @click="selectSubCategory(subCategory)">
      <div class="title">{{ subCategory.title }}</div>
      <div class="arrow">></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</VuePerfectScrollbar>
```

So, the subCategories property relies on category object, which I set simply:

```
selectCategory(category) {
  this.category = category
},
```

When user selects a category.

I specified :key, tried different approaches but nothing worked, I always get the old list of subCategories.

What could be the reason?

**update**

Vuex getter:

```
export const getClothingSubCategories = (state) => {
  return state.clothingSubCategories
}
```

Component data:

```
data() {
    return {
      gender: 'female',
      category: null,
      subCategory: null,
      good: null,

      filters: {
        gender: 'female',
        clothing_subcategory_id: null
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Show the code for the getter `this.getClothingSubCategories`, and most  importantly, where you change the category in the Vuex store: the mutation and the code (in a component) that calls that mutation.

Comment: I change category only in component. When user selects a category from category list, I set components data (this.category = category)

Comment: Can you paste the `data` of the component?

Comment: Sure, updated my question

Comment: Having the `category` initially `null`, doesn't `this.category.clothing_category_id` in the `subCategories` computed throw an exception?

Comment: No, because I display subcategory list only if category is selected. Though I also tried to add "if (!category) return[]" or something like this...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167960/discussion-between-victor-and-acdcjunior).

Comment: At what point, and how are you creating the category object that you send as argument to `selectCategory(category) {
  this.category = category
},`? Can you show the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your declaration:

```html
<VuePerfectScrollbar class="categories"
                     v-if="showSubCategories"
                     v-once>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="subCategory in subCategories"
        :key="subCategory.clothing_subcategory_id"
        @click="selectSubCategory(subCategory)">
      <div class="title">{{ subCategory.title }}</div>
      <div class="arrow">></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</VuePerfectScrollbar>
```

The `subCategories` value, which is a computed property:

```
subCategories() {
  return this.getClothingSubCategories.filter((subCategory) => {
    return subCategory.clothing_category_id === this.category.clothing_category_id
  })
},
```

is supposed to be updated whenever `category` changes.

As you reported, it does. As it should.

Your problem, though is:

> ## [`v-once`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-once)
>
> **Details:**
>
> Render the element and component once only. On subsequent re-renders,
> the element/component and all its children will be treated as static
> content and skipped. This can be used to optimize update performance.

That is, as soon as Vue renders the subcategory collection the first time it "freezes" it. Basically, because of `v-once` it will never be updated again.

**Solution:** remove `v-once`.

I suggest you remove from other places in your code as well. Any element you want to be updated should not have `v-once`.

Comment: Owe you a drink or so!

Comment: Haha! If I ever go to Russia, let's make sure that debt is payed!